# New HTML/CSS code doesn't pass post variables to PHP shell_exec

Tags: php, html, css

I created an HTML form that passes variables to an `exec_shell`. Everything worked perfectly until I added CSS to my HTML page. The new HTML+CSS code doesn't pass the variables to the php `shell_exec`.

Before (working):

```
<body>
    <form action="adduser.php" method="post">
        Server: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" name="name"><br>
        Password: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

After (not working):

```
<form  action="adduser.php" method="post" class="contact3-form validate-form">
    <span class="contact3-form-title">
        Title
    </span>

    <div class="wrap-input3 validate-input" data-validate="Server Name is required">
        <input class="input3" type="text" value="<?php echo $hosts; ?>" name="hosts" placeholder="Server Name or Server Group">
        <span class="focus-input3"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-input3 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid Password is required">
        <input class="input3" type="text" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" name="password" placeholder="Your Password">
        <span class="focus-input3"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="container-contact3-form-btn">
        <button class="contact3-form-btn">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I also tried:

```
value="<' . $hosts .'"
```

Is there a better way to do it than HTML ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your button doesn't have type and value

Answer (score 0):

your button don't have type="submit"

Comment: @kashif-rafique I already tried <button type="submit"  formmethod="post" class="contact3-form-btn">
                                                        Submit
                                                </button>
with or without formmethod or with the old submit, tried deleting the placeholder from the input tag since the placeholder is replaced anyway by "<?php echo $hosts ?>" and "<?php echo $password ?>"

Comment: what message is displayed?

Comment: nothing, I have an PHP error in http log: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$password' (T_VARIABLE). $password being the second $_POST variable